# Concatenate a numpy array of strings to numpy array of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am learning multiple linear regression in python, and for one particular instance I have the following equation: `y=b+m1x1+m2x2+...+m5x5`. I will like to print out the  same equation on my terminal in the same format with the values inserted for `m` and `b`

As of now I have the following code implemented:

```
insert numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
...
print("b= ",regressor.intercept_) # b= 42467.529248548686
m= np.array(regressor.coef_)
print(m) # [8.66e+01 -8.73e+02  7.86e+02  7.73e-01  3.29e-02  3.66e-02] 
x_var= ['x'+ str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
print(x_var) # it gives ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5']
```

I know that my question might be super basic, but how should how do I concatenate the numpy array of integers **m** with array of strings **x_var**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `numpy` arrays are primarily numeric, like your `m`.  While you can create an array of strings, mixing strings and numbers is not a good `numpy` fit.  So feel free to use list methods, such as `zip` and string formatting.  This isn't an array concatenating task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the zip function:

```
equation = []
for coef, var in zip(m, [''] + x_var):
    equation.append(str(coef) + var)

print(" + ".join(equation))
```

or

```
equation = [str(m[0])]
for coef, var in zip(m[1:], x_var):
    equation.append(str(coef) + var)

print(" + ".join(equation))
```